# How to create a submit button with ui-sref in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, submit

I have a multi-step form, each step having a `btn-link` to move to the next step. I achieve this with angular routes in this way:

```
<button ui-sref="next.step" class="btn btn-link"></button>
```

In one of the steps in the middle of the whole form I need to submit the data, so I need the already described button to submit the form as well and only if the form could be submitted then move to the next step.
I tried doing this but it is not working because it redirects to the next step without taking care about the form

```
<button ui-sref="next.step2" type="submit" class="btn btn-link"></button>
```

How can I achieve this using angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you **don't need to use ui-sref** for your next button instead use [`$state`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) service from your controller as shown below

**HTML Code**

```
<form ng-submit="onFormSubmission($event)">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link"></button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
var successCallback = function(response) {
    //process response
    $state.go("next.step2");
}

$scope.onFormSubmission = function($event) {

    var data = getFormData();

    $http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

}
```

Comment: is it necessary to pass `$event` to the function?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-submit` to submit the form and show some loading message as form is getting saved, use `$http` to post the data and on-success take user to next route using `$state.go`.

```
<script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'hello';
      $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.get('/aveData', config).then(function(response){
           $state.go('next.step2')
        }, function(){
           alert('error saving data');
        });
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Although your answer works too, I find the one from S4beR easier to understand. I cannot accept both, sorry